# layout:alignParentStart установить програмно

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Есть `TextView` c `id=text`. Мне нужно в одной части кода `layoutParentStart` на `true`, а в другой на `false`. Если кто не понял, то в xml это неотмеченое окошко)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [align parent start android programmatically](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=align%20parent%20start%20android%20programmatically)
2. [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4639012/3212712)
3. Ответ:

   ```
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
   params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);

   button.setLayoutParams(params);
   ```